# dplyr filter if a column starts with one of the strings in a list

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Our objective: Using R dplyr, filter the row if the data in the match_column field starts with one of the codes in the code_list <- c("123", "234", "456").

The following works for a static string (i.e., it returns all the rows from dataset::match_column that begin with static string "123".)

```
dataset1 <-filter(dataset, str_detect(match_column,"^123"))
```

After numerous attempts, we can't figure out the syntax to replace "^123" with the code_list.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `paste` the strings with `collapse` to do the `filter` to filter the rows of the dataset column ('match_column') that have either one of the elements in the 'code_list'

```
library(tidyverse)
pat <-  paste0("^(", paste(code_list, collapse = "|"), ")")
dataset %>%
     filter(str_detect(match_column, pat))
```

If it is to just use one of the elements from 'code_list'

```
dataset %>%
     filter(str_detect(match_column, paste0("^", code_list[1])))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, your solution was what we needed. Once we added a "^" after "|" (... collapse = "|^" ...) the filter seems to be working perfectly. Thank you again.